# Express-session stops saving sessions after a while

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, session

I have a rather elusive issue where express stops saving session data in the session store (MongoDB) or client-side cookie after about a day of uptime. Restarting the server-side API server seems to solve the issue, but only for another day or so and then it reoccurs and has to be restarted again.

The node app is running on Ubuntu 16 and I can't find any log messages relating to the issue.

I will paste the login code below which sets the session data,

```
router.post('/login', async function(req, res) {
var user_name = req.body.user_name;
var password = req.body.password;
var currentTime = new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes();

if(user_name && password) { // If both the username and password were sent.
  User.findOne({"field_data.user_name": user_name}).select('password 
  field_data').then( async (user) => {
    if(!user) { // A record was not found.
      console.log(currentTime + " - Failed Login: " + user_name);
      var returnResult = {
        error: true,
        msg: "User Not Found."
      };
      res.json(returnResult);
    } else { // A record was found.
      console.log(currentTime + " - User Logged in: " + 
      user.field_data.first_name + " " + user.field_data.last_name);
      let result = await user.CheckCredentials(password);
      if(result) {
        var returnResult = {
          error: false,
          msg: "Logged In: " + user.field_data.first_name + " " + 
          user.field_data.last_name,
          data: {
            first_name: user.field_data.first_name,
            last_name: user.field_data.last_name,
            user_roles: user.field_data.user_role,
            id: user._id
          }
        };

        // Set session data which creates record in session store and client 
        // cookie.
        req.session.userId = user.id;
        req.session.userRoles = user.field_data.user_role ;
        req.session.userName = user.field_data.first_name + " " + 
        user.field_data.last_name;
        req.session.save(); // This line makes no difference.

      } else {
        var returnResult = {
          error: true,
          msg: "Invalid Credentials!"
        };
      }
      res.json(returnResult);
    }

  }).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e)
  });
} else {
  res.json({error: true, msg: "Invalid username/password!"});
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your sessions maxAge s are expiring. 
I used redis you can make the changes as you wish

```
var express = require("express");
var session = require('express-session');

var sessionConfig = {
    secret: "your_secret",
    store: // new redisStore({ client: redis.getClient() }),
    resave: true,
    rolling: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { maxAge: 30 * 60000 }
}

var app = express();
app.use(session(sessionConfig));

app.post('/somepath', (req,res,next)=>{
        // find your user or else 
        req.session.userData = {
            id : user.id,
            roles : user.field_data.user_role ,
            name : user.field_data.first_name
        }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It turned out to be an issue with my session/cookie server config, I was using a mixture of settings with my session store without fully understanding them I guess! - I had "touchAfter" set with "maxAge" and "resave" set to false, I was also not aware of the "rolling" setting. I've managed to solve the issue by basing my settings on yours. However I'm not certain why the app would stop creating any new sessions after a point.

Comment: you mean new sessions are not created on the server side? it's strange, does it throw an exception or just empty session objects? maybe your connection to session storage is broken somehow?

Comment: It's all working now with the new config. I'm just confused as to what was causing the issue previously, it would appear to work fine but then after about a day it would just stop creating any new session items in the session store and not save any session cookies on the client-side. As far as I could see there were no errors being thrown anywhere.